# Word Add-in changes required (but everything seems to be ok from my part)

Tags: office-store

I am trying to publish an Word Add-In to Office store and I have received a validation report saying that there is an issue with my add-in, respectively that it appears to be loading blank (no other details). Then the report says that I should remedy the problem and resubmit the add-in.

However, when I am testing my add-in in Word Online and Word for Office 365 everything is working. I have debugged the add-in with Visual Studio 2017 and there is no problem with it.

It seems i cannot replicate the issue encountered by Microsoft Team and I am kind of stuck with this issue because i do not know what changes I should make.

Therefore my question is how can I know what generated the issue describe in the report?

The fun part of the report is that it mentions that I should contact Microsoft for helping me solving the issue. No point of contact is provided though.

The local customer support for Office 365, says they are not dealing with this kind o developer issues and the support link in the developer account sends me to buy a support ticket of 25 Euro, although I am not in the position to know what the problem is (just that it seems to be a problem).

From [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-the-office-store) I have found that i can contact AppSource Validation Team via StackOveflow and here i am, although seems kind of weird to discuss the issue in a public forum.

Comment: Where are you loading the add-in from? If it's a static website provider, perhaps they've went down during the Microsoft testing? Are you fetching everything from your CDN or do you have dependencies that might have gone down? Are you making a server call which could have taken longer / perhaps your server was unhealthy...There are a lot of different things that could have went wrong, have you validated these?

Comment: @Mavi Domates Hi! I eventually contacted the App Source team and get more details about the error and it was a logical error for my side which prevented the load of the add-in in one of the language supported by add-in. Actually I was checking the existence of the English language but failed to realize that there are more version of English (en-us, en-uk, and so on). Now the problem was solved and the add-in approved! Thanks for your reply!